# Action Script 3. Randomize radio buttons values and labels

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, random, radio-button

So I have window where are question and 2 radio buttons. In AS3 I added to answers **labels** and **values**. It looks like something like:

```
       function myAnswers(e:MouseEvent):void {
            answer.rb1.label = "Answer 1"; // This answer should be always CORRECT
            answer.rb2.label = "Answer 2"; // This answer should be always INCORRECT

            answer.rb1.value = "TRUE"; // Here I set for rb1 value "TRUE"
            answer.rb2.value = "FALSE"; // Here I set for rb2 value "FALSE"
        }
```

How can I **randomize** these **answers** and always keep Answer 1 with TRUE value?[image: randomize]

I mean If I set for rb1 label = "Answer 1" I need to set for rb1 value = "TRUE".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Math.random()` method to determine whether `rb1` or `rb2` should contain the "correct" answer:

```
function myAnswers(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // First, we decide whether rb1 or rb2 should be the "correct" radio button
    var correctRadio:RadioButton = Math.random() > .5 ? answer.rb1 : answer.rb2;
    // Then, we set incorrectRadio to the opposite of correct radio
    var inccorrectRadio:RadioButton = correctRadio == answer.rb1 ? answer.rb2 : answer.rb1;

    // Finally, we set the labels and values on the "correct" and "incorrect" radio buttons
    correctRadio.label = "Answer 1"; // This answer should be always CORRECT
    inccorrectRadio.label = "Answer 2"; // This answer should be always INCORRECT

    correctRadio.value = "TRUE"; // Here I set the correct radio value "TRUE"
    inccorrectRadio.value = "FALSE"; // Here I set the incorrect radio value "FALSE"
}
```